# Add image to QQuickView

Tags: c++, qt

What I need to do is adding an image (available as a QImage object) to a custom QQuickItem.
I override the updatePaintNode() function and add a couple of nodes, one of which should have a triangle-shaped child note. I´d like to achieve this by using an image of triangle contained in a png-file.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood your requirements. You need QQuickWindow::createTextureFromImage to create a QSGTexture, then a QSGSimpleTextureNode with the texture you just created, plus a QSGGeometry to define its geometry.

Comment: Good to hear, that´s what I´ve been trying to do. Do I have to call it on the parent-instance of my QuickView?